# image processing for a noob

Tags: image-processing

i have been given a project where i will need to write code such that it parts of images. For example the project will require me to extract a river part from the scenery or so. I have no experience in this context. Please tell me where do i start studying form. Which are good books? Which technologies will i need to learn. What are the tools that are helpful?

Comment: Do you have programming experience relevant to handling image data?

Comment: This question belongs to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing

Comment: @Thornbjorn: I have no experience with any image handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is probably the most complete free image processing library.
There is also a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) which describes both the library and some image processing techniques.

This is a reasonably complex problem, not exactly graduate research but challenging!

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207092/image-processing-textbook) for a list of other books.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) is an easy to use, scriptable, modular, open source software, which may be quite useful in learning image processing. As for books, [Digital Image Processing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-3E/dip3e_main_page.htm) by Gonzalez et al. is de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this Q is closed but I recommend [NetPBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) and similar packages.  This allows you to define images as text and perform operations but in a manner (albeit slow processing) that makes it very easy to understand.